# How to use for loop inside computed property inside struct in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Very new to native iOS, i have a struct :

```swift
struct PrayerTime: View{
  let prayerTime:[String:String]
  
  var prayerName : String {
    for (key, _) in prayerTime {
      return key.description
    }
  } // error :Missing return in a function expected to return 'String'
  
  var time : String {
    for (_, value) in prayerTime {
      return value
    }
  } // error :Missing return in a function expected to return 'String'
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Text(prayerName).scaledToFill().minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
      Text(time).bold().scaledToFill().minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
    }
  }
}
```

I want to extract key and value of dictionary in separate properties.

> Note that the dictionary has only one key:value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because both properties don't return anything if the dictionary is empty. You have to write

```
var prayerName : String {
    for (key, _) in prayerTime {
      return key.description
    }
    return ""
}
```

But as the dictionary contains only one key/value pair there is a simpler way

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Text(prayerTime.keys.first ?? "").scaledToFill().minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
      Text(prayerTime.values.first ?? "").bold().scaledToFill().minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
    }
}
```

and delete both computed properties

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `prayerTime` might be empty, in which case the `for` loop is not executed and hence nothing is returned.

If you want to return the first key/value from your `Dictionary`, you shouldn't use a loop at all. You should instead use the `keys` and `values` properties of your `Dictionary` and access their first element using `first`.

```
var prayerName : String {
    prayerTime.keys.first ?? ""
}

var time : String {
  prayerTime.values.first ?? ""
}
```

However, if you `prayerTime` is guaranteed to contain a single key-value pair, you're much better off simply injecting the key and value as separate variables, no need for a `Dictionary`.

```
struct PrayerTime: View{
    let prayerName: String
    let time: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(prayerName).scaledToFill().minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
            Text(time).bold().scaledToFill().minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
        }
    }
}
```